# A Compact Metric Space

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

let $ X = \{ x = ( x )_{n=1}^{\infty} \mid x_n \in \mathbb{R}, \quad o \leq x_n \leq 1 \quad \forall n \in \mathbb{N} \} $.

The set $X$ equipped with metric $d(x,y) = sup \{ \mid x_n - y_n \mid : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$.

> **Is $(X,d)$ a Compact Metric Space?**

Comment: It's called a compact metric space...

Comment: You recieved an answer to your question. Is it what you needed? If so, you should upvote and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not compact. Let $x^{(n)}$ be the sequence with $1$ at the n-th place and $0$ elsewhere. Then $\{x^{(n)}\}$ has no convergent subsequence because the distance between $x^{(n)}$ and $x^{(m)}$ is $1$ whenever $n \neq m$ (which implies that no subsequence is Cauchy).